# Why p, *p, &*p have the same value when p is a two dimension array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When `p` is a pointer to an array, why :

```cpp
*p == p == &*p
```

Simple program, just a two dimension arrays in c++ :

```cpp
int p[][3] = {{1,2,3}};
```

```
cout << p << " " << *p << " " << &*p;
```

> result: 0x22fe20 0x22fe20 0x22fe20

Comment: Why wouldn't they be the same value? You didn't specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an array's value is used (`p` in this case), it implicitly converts to pointer to first element (same as `&p[0]`). Such conversion is called decaying.

Also, the first element of an array is at the same address where the array is.

- `p` decays to `&p[0]`. It is the address of the first element of `p` which is the same address as the array `p` itself.
- `*p` Here, the `p` first decays to `&p[0]`, so the full expression is equivalent to `*&p[0]`. The `*&` cancel each other out (by definition in C; C++ uses different wording, but the effect is the same) As such, it is an lvalue to `p[0]` i.e. the first element of the array. In this case, that element is another array, and so its value decays to pointer to the first element (i.e. `&p[0][0]`). Since the address of the first element is the same as the address of the array, the address of `p[0][0]` is same as address of `p[0]` which is same as address of `p`.
- `&*p` As before, `&*` cancel each other out and result is same as using  just `p`.

---

In memory, a 4x4 2D array looks like this:

```
  *
..0000111122223333..
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  YYYY
  Z
```

In this diagram, each column represents a memory location. Columns marked with `X` are where the 2D array is stored.

Each column marked with 0 is an element of the first subarray, and each one with 1 are elements of the second subarray and so forth.

Columns marked with `Y` are where the first subarray is stored.

Column marked with `Z` is the first element of the first subarray.

As you may notice, `X`, `Y` and `Z` all start on the same address marked with `*`. This is the address of the array, the address of the first subarray and the address of the first element of the first subarray.

Comment: can i understand like this:p is a pointer to a pointer which is a pointer to a 1D array

Comment: @Ethic Not quite, because `p` is not a pointer. `p` is an array. But `p` does decay to a pointer to a 1D array (the first element).

Comment: I see it's just when to treat the array name as variable and when to treat it as address

Answer (score 3):

The array `p` decays to a pointer to its first element when you print it. That's the same as `&p`. As for `&*p` that's the address of whatever the dereferenced `p` points to. Which is again the first element - same as the first two.

The type are different though. Even if the addresses are the same. `p` is an array, but `&p` is a pointer to `int` array.

Comment: I want to add that type of `&p` differs from the type of the other two.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sure, but the question was about the addresses. And those are all the same. Anyway; I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer to the beginning of the array.

`*p` is a pointer to the first array in that array (aka the beginning of the array)

`&*p` is the same thing as `p`, syntactically.

Comment: `p` is an array. Sure, it easily decays to a pointer, but its type is still an array. `&p` is never an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array declared for example like this

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

then used in expressions (with rare exceptions as for example an operand of the operator sizeof) the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So in this statement

```
std::cout << a;
```

is the same as

```
std::cout << &a[0];
```

or the same as

```
std::cout << &*a;
```

In your example `*p` is an array `{1,2,3}` that represents the first element of the array `p`.

Used as an expression in the statement

```
std::cout << *p;
```

it is converted to the address of its first element that is it is the address of the first element equal to 1.

All these addresses point to the start of the extent allocated to the array. So though the types of for example the expression `p` and expression `*p` are different (the first expression has the type `int ( * )[3]` and the second expression has the type `int *`) nevertheless their values are equal.